# How to change Iconbutton once you click on it to a different Iconbutton

Tags: dart, flutter

i want to change the icon on the IconButton once you click on it then make my slider slideup. so like this 
when you click list view - slides up
when you click map- slides down

```
bool _pressAttention = true;

IconButton(
     icon: (_pressAttention? Icon(Icons.view_list, color: Colors.grey): Icon(Icons.map, color: Colors.grey)), 
     onPressed: (){
         setState(() {
              if (_pressAttention=true){
                   _pc.open();

                  } else{
                     _pc.close();

                    } 
                    });
                  } 
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement needs `==` instead of `=` or you can shorten it down to `if (_pressAttention) {`. Also you're never changing `_pressAttention`'s value. First make sure you put `_pressAttention = true` between `Widget build(BuildContext context) {` and `return`, otherwise it will be true on every reload. Then change your code to this:

```dart
setState(() {
  _pressAttention = _pressAttention ? false : true;

  if (_pressAttention) {
    _pc.open();
  } else {
    _pc.close();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
 _pressAttention ?
    IconButton(
        icon:  Icon(Icons.view_list, color: Colors.grey) , onPressed: () => setState(() {  _pc.open();})) :
  IconButton(
      icon:  Icon(Icons.map, color: Colors.grey) , onPressed: () => setState(() {  _pc.close();}) );
```